# How to align a component to the center/right with Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to align my button to the right of the parent.

I was wondering if there is a *proper* way to do it in Material UI. I could use:

```
<Grid container justify="flex-end">
```

But then I would have to use another `<Grid item />`. Seems like too much work.

Or maybe I am just better off using plain old CSS, messing around with `float: right`, and dealing with the apparent zero height of the element.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

#### BEFORE Material UI 5:

Try this

```
<Grid container justify="flex-end">
  <Button>Example</Button>
</Grid>
```

#### UPDATE Material UI 5: (Thanks to Dipak)

> The prop `justify` of `ForwardRef(Grid)` is deprecated. Use `justifyContent` instead, the prop was renamed.

```
<Grid container justifyContent="flex-end">
  <Button>Example</Button>
</Grid>
```

#### Update: The best solutions are the answers of NearHuscarl or Eduardo Oviedo Blanco, you'd rather use Stack or Box than Grid.

Comment: What if there are two Grid items inside container Grid and I want to align only second one right?

Comment: then you transform your item into a container (a grid can be both)
so your item would be something like : <Grid item xs={6} container justify="flex-end">

Comment: Adding `<Grid item xs={12} sm={6} container justifyContent="flex-end">` worked for me. Had to use `justifyContent`

Answer (score 49):

If you would like to align items within the `<Grid item>` you can  use a wrapping `Box` component as follows:

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item sm={6}>
    <Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-end">
      <Button>Button Aligned To The Right</Button>
    </Box>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

See the [docs](https://mui.com/system/flexbox/) for more positioning options.

Answer (score 14):

In **Material UI v5**, you can use [`Stack`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stack/) to display a set of components on a row or a column. `Stack` is a flexbox so you only need to set the `justifyContent` prop to align the item inside:

```
<Stack direction="row" justifyContent="end">
  <Button variant="contained">Item 1</Button>
</Stack>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use the Grid component, you have to rely on CSS.

But if you use Material-UI you should use JSS (CSS-IN-JS) and not plain CSS.

- Introduction : https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/
- Benefits : http://cssinjs.org/benefits

In CSS you may use any of these solutions for example. "text-align" being the simplest one.

- `text-align: right`
- `float: right`
- flexbox

  - parent with : `display: flex`
  - child with : `align-content: flex-end`

Answer (score 3):

Use the Box component with flex.

```
<Box display="flex" flexDirection="column" >
  <... other stuff/>
</Box>
```

You can learn more [here](https://material-ui.com/system/flexbox/)

Answer (score 2):

```
            <Toolbar sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
                <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: 600 }}>
                    Recent Repositories
                </Typography>
                <Box>
                    {/* <Typography></Typography> */}
                    <Button error>+ New</Button>
                </Box>
            </Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Latest material-ui version 5** use justifyContent="flex-end" or alignContent which is equivalent to css text-align and flex-end=right

```
    <Grid container alignContent="flex-end">
         <Button>Example</Button>
    </Grid>

or
    <Grid item justifyContent="flex-end">
         <Button>Example</Button>
    </Grid>
```

**For old material-ui version 4**

```
    <Grid item justify="flex-end">
         <Button>Example</Button>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: With `v4.11.4` only `<Grid container justify="flex-end">` works. Your examples don't work for me.

Comment: Thanks, it is working for me and save my time.

Comment: Instead of "Latest" [at the time of writing] and "old" can you specify versions?

Answer (score 0):

As this question is not specified towards Grid, here a more general answer:

there are other components for which the parameters need to be provided in an sx.

```
<Toolbar sx={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
```

Answer (score -3):

Material UI's Grid Component has helper props to achieve this.

```
<Grid align-items-xs-center justify-xs-flex-end>
 <Button>Click me</Button>
</Grid>
```

You can find the docs [here](https://material-ui.com/api/grid/#css-api).

Comment: probably in older version, and does not answer the question