# Material UI v5 Align Inline Typography Component to the right

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, typography, text-align

I just upgraded to MUI Version 5.4 and now my Inline Typography does not align right anymore.

This is my Code that worked for MUI Version 4:

```
<Grid container xs={12}>
  <Grid container xs={12} justify="space-between" style={{borderBottom: "3px solid black"}}>
    <Typography inline>Value</Typography>
    <Typography inline align="right">{prodVol}MWh</Typography>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

My Guess is, that there is a Problem with the new Grid, because when I changed that Import the Code stopped working.

Comment: Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159071/mui-how-to-align-a-component-to-the-center-right).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159071/mui-how-to-align-a-component-to-the-center-right), I just replaced "justify" with "justifyContent".

My Working Code for MUI V5:

```
<Grid container xs={12}>
  <Grid container xs={12} justifyContent="space-between" style={{borderBottom: "3px solid black"}}>
    <Typography inline>Value</Typography>
    <Typography inline align="right">{prodVol}MWh</Typography>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Thanks Medi :)